# Pandas plot multiple dataframes, one dataframe produces a flatline

Tags: pandas, plot

I've got two dataframes with their own values. When i would like to have them plot into one graph, the result is that i only see the data from one of the dataframes.

```
gdpgraph['sum'] = gdpgraph['sum'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
gdpgraph.info()
```

Index: 18 entries, 2000 to 2017
Data columns (total 1 columns):
sum    18 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 928.0+ bytes

```
graphsoccer = soccer.groupby(['Year'])['Amount'].agg(['sum'])
graphsoccer.info()
```

Index: 18 entries, 2000 to 2017
Data columns (total 1 columns):
sum    18 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
gdpgraph['sum'].plot(ax=ax)
graphsoccer['sum'].plot(ax=ax)
```

The result is a graph with only the graphsoccer information the other dataframe is flat.

Your help is very welcome.

Comment: looks like it should work... what do you mean by flat? Are you able to add the plot to the question? Maybe check the underlying data? What is `gdpgraph['sum'].describe()` for example?

Comment: [link]https://cloudgeek.nl/plot2.png

Comment: Both dataframes contain on their axes, years and the other axes contain values. There are no NaN values or empty strings.

Comment: Maybe a scaling issue? what is `graphsoccer['sum'].describe()` ?

Comment: count    1.800000e+01
mean     2.212522e+09
std      9.555994e+08
min      1.071060e+09
25%      1.580572e+09
50%      2.070600e+09
75%      2.442665e+09
max      4.706270e+09
Name: sum, dtype: float64

Comment: Strange thing is that the graphsoccer data is displayed correctly but the gdpgraph is a flatline.

Comment: Yeh it's your scaling... 1 frames values are in 100Ms and the other is in 10s. You'll need to either scale the data or use a secondary axis

Comment: I'll see how i can get a secondary axis in the graph, thanks for pointing this out Chris!

Answer (score 1):

This is a scaling issue with your data, one `DataFrame` values is in 100M's and one is in 100's.

You could create a secondary axis to plot one of your Series:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()

gdpgraph['sum'].plot(ax=ax)
graphsoccer['sum'].plot(ax=ax2)
```

Or

```
gdpgraph['sum'].plot(ax=ax)
graphsoccer['sum'].plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome help!

Comment: @Spanhaak no problem

Comment: Is there also a way to show the x-axes values? both df's have a Year column. I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Does adding `ax.set_xticklabels(graphsoccer.index)` fix?

Comment: Yes it does, but i have the idea that the amount of ticks should be more to better match the data. i now see the year 2001 - 2008 while the data has 2000 - 2017 as years, is there a way to extend the ticks?

Comment: hmmm not sure without some sample data to try with

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
gdpgraph['sum'].plot(ax=ax)
graphsoccer['sum'].plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
plt.show()
```